# If $E$ is a finitely presented left $A$-module, then tensor product by E commutes with direct product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Please can anyone help me to prove this statement:

> If $E$ is a finitely presented left $A$-module, then
>   for every family $(F_i)$ of right $A$-modules the canonical homomorphism $\phi: E\bigotimes_A \prod F_i \rightarrow  \prod (E\bigotimes _A F_i)$ is an isomorphism.

I have proved that the map is surjective, and I want anyone to help me to prove that the map is injective.

Thank you!